# The generalization of Brouwer's fixed point theorem?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a contractible compact [edit: locally connected] topological space 
(Hausdorff and second countable). Let $f\colon X\to X$
be a continuous map. Then (I suppose) $f$ has a fixed 
point. Personally, I cannot think of a better generalization 
of Brouwer's fixed point theorem, but is it true?

Comment: It is true if $X$ is triangulable by the Lefschetz fixed point theorem. I don't know what happens if $X$ is not triangulable. 

Comment: Alex:  it is generally considered to be bad etiquette to edit your question substantively after answers have been posted (and accepted!).  It might be worth reading some of the literature (e.g. Bing's article) and then posting a new question, with whatever information you discover upon doing so.  

Comment: [Similar MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4449267/84253)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No.  I believe the first counterexample is from:

Kinoshita, S. On Some Contractible Continua without Fixed Point Property. Fund. Math. 40 (1953), 96-98

which I unfortunately can't find online.  Kinoshita's example is described on page 127 in this excellent [article by Bing](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317258), however.

EDIT:  The question has been revised to add the local connectivity condition; as stated, I think the question is open.  If "contractible" is replaced with "acyclic" there are counterexamples dating back to Borsuk, referenced e.g. [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http%253A%252F%252Fmatwbn.icm.edu.pl%252Fksiazki%252Ffm%252Ffm107%252Ffm10711.pdf&ei=VteSTYmMDInmsQPd_PW9Cw&usg=AFQjCNH6ceZLPpJxw5lVy0sc-p_8DdudaQ&sig2=Zr9Sn7SIVPRC1dpyhggXAA); Borsuk's paper, which I can't find online, is:

K. Borsuk, Sur un continua acyclique qui se laisse transformer topologiquement en lui-meme sans points invariants, Fund. Math. 24 (1935), pp. 51-58.

This suggests that if the OP's conjecture is true, it is unlikely to be open to homological attacks.

Comment: The original article can be found at: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm40/fm4019.pdf

Comment: Thank you. The example is nice! 
(By the way, why he call a compactum a continuum?)

Comment: Oops! I know why he call it this. What I do not know is how to 
delete my own foolish remark:(

Comment: I do not know if it is a right policy, but i added the local connectedness  condition. Surely I missed it initially. 

Comment: @Alex: adding details to your questions is perfectly fine and should be encouraged. If you feel like you need to point out that a detail was not there before, you can always write it like: Let X be a contractible compact [edit: locally connected] topological space

Comment: Explanation: The statement should be of kind "Let $X$ looks like a ball. Then...". Definitely, Kinoshita's example does not look like 
a ball, for it is not locally connected. So, I added this condition to rule it out.

Comment: Daniel, Let me explain myself. Suppose for a moment that the 
question was "A continuous map of a good contractible compact topological 
space into itself has a fixed point" (Which is what I mean, actually). 
You gave an example, I did not accept it for the space is not 
good enough for me. Would you like this? I failed to foresee 
all the possible pathology: the fault is mine. 
But is it a good reason to create a new question? I doubt it.

P.S. By the way, could anyone give me Bing's article?
For now, I cannot get it from where I am. 

Comment: Alex, don't worry about it; the change was understandable.  I am unaware of an answer to the revised question, and have done some searching; as far as I can tell it is open.  If you replace "contractible" with "acyclic," however, there are counterexamples, i.e. locally connected acyclic compact spaces without the fixed point property.  I've edited my answer to remark on this.

Comment: Alex, as for the Bing paper, if you email me, I'd be happy to send it to you.  My email is on my user page.