# Is there a generalization of Brouwer's fixed point theorem?

Tags: gn.general-topology

In essence, this is the same problem as in 
“[The generalization of Brouwer's fixed point theorem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59796/the-generalization-of-brouwers-fixed-point-theorem)”.
But now I am determined to be careful. The main question is 
the following:

Is there any generalization of Brouwer's fixed point theorem 
in terms of general topology? (That is, without triangulations, 
or vector spaces, or anything else).

The question is a bit vague, but, I hope, it admits a
precise answer. Now, I am trying my best to propose a candidate.

Let $X$ be a contractible locally contractible
Hausdorff second countable  compact topological space. 
Let $f\colon X\to X$ be a continuous map. 
Has then $f$ a fixed point?

Comment: I do not have the answer but these matters are discussed extensively in Bing "The elusive fixed point property". Amer. Math. Monthly 76 1969 119–132. http://www.jstor.org/pss/2317258.  

Comment: As I remarked in my answer to your previous question, this seems to be open.