# Brouwer fixed point theorem for non-Hausdorff spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Can the Brouwer fixed point theorem be formulated for non-Hausdorff spaces ?

More particularly, is there a formulation of the Brouwer fixed point theorem
which covers both the standard case of metrizable spaces, and the case of finite topological spaces ?

For example, is the following true:

> Each endomorphism of a quasi-compact $T_0$ space
> which is an absolute extensor for normal spaces, necessarily has a fixed point.

As pointed out in comments by Michael Greinecker, [Kinoshita, 1953](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm40/fm4019.pdf) gives a counterexample to the following which is a contractible compact subset of $\Bbb R^3$, see also [Bing,The elusive fixed point property](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317258) and references in [The generalization of Brouwer's fixed point theorem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59796/the-generalization-of-brouwers-fixed-point-theorem).

> Each endomorphism of a contractible quasi-compact $T_0$ space necessarily has a fixed point. (false!)

hence we replace "contractible" by "absolute extensor"

Note that being $T_0$ is necessary: the indiscrete space with two points is quasi-compact and contractible, yet the permutation of the two points has no fixed point. Perhaps one can relax the notion of a fixed point, e.g. by requiring that $x$ and $f(x)$ are topologically indistinguishable.

By the Brouwer theorem for finite topological spaces I mean what is implied by the Brouwer fixed point theorem for the geometric realisation of a finite topological space: namely, an endomorphism $f:K\to K$ of a finite topological space $K$ has a fixed point provided the endomorphism $\lvert f\rvert\colon\lvert K\rvert\to\lvert K\rvert$ of the geometric realisation of $K$ has a fixed point.

Comment: There is a famous example by Kinoshita of a contractible compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that lacks the topological fixed-point property.

Comment: Thanks! I replaced "contractible" with "absolute extensor for normal spaces", which is different. Would that help ? Is this counterexample an absolute extensor for normal spaces ?

Comment: I'm not that knowledgable when it comes to algebraic topology, but "acyclic absolute neighborhood retract" is enough by a fixed-point theorem of Eilenberg and Montgomery.

Comment: What is the geometric realization in the last paragraph?

Comment: @Z.M this is what is defined in the [Clader's thesis](https://pages.uoregon.edu/lipshitz/Teaching/CladerThesis.pdf). ( I seem to recall people writing there was an inaccuracy/error there but do not recall at the moment). Maybe also see this [How much of homotopy theory can be done using only finite topological spaces?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177461/how-much-of-homotopy-theory-can-be-done-using-only-finite-topological-spaces)

Comment: So does it imply that spectral spaces also have this property, since spectral spaces are [characterized](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09XX) by being cofiltered limits of finite sober (or equivalently, $T_0$-)spaces?

Comment: I mean, the geometric realization of spectral spaces is defined to be the right Kan extension from finite sober spaces, so it will take value in compact Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: Which 'this property'? I think the usual geometric realisation of a poset (viewed as a simplicial set of its chains or some such) is a retract of a filtered colimit of barycentric subdivisions, see [this thesis, Theorem 2.4.14](https://www.proquest.com/docview/1424274072) which claims it is at least homotopy equivalent, referenced by P.May.

Comment: In fact, the modification of contractibility I'd like to use is as follows: X is such that that $X\to \{pt\}$ is in the left-then-right orthogonal of a particular map $M\to\Lambda$ of finite topological spaces which is an acyclic Serre fibration and is a model of barycentric subdivision of the interval, defined in [the list here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lift#iterated_lifting_properties). It is somewhat similar to being an absolute extensor.

Comment: Without knowing anything about finite topological spaces, I'm surprised that the generalisation of the BFPT you mention is true. I would have guessed that the geometric realisation $|K|$ of the two-point space with the indiscrete topology $K$ is the closed interval. However, the involution that swaps the two points has no fixed point in $K$, but induces a homeomorphism that fixes a point in $|K|$. Apologies if I've misunderstood; I'm entirely ignorant of this subject!

Comment: @HJRW OP mentioned this in the post: the necessity of $T_0$.

Comment: By "this property", I mean the fixed point property that you want — namely, that property on spectral spaces (but that does not incorporate the version for compact Hausdorff spaces that you want). As I explained, spectral spaces are "profinite" sober spaces.

Comment: So is there a form of fixed point theorem for spectral spaces ?

Comment: @Z. M : As for now, I do not know. I am following up the references by @ 
Michael Greinecker, and may update the post with references and a conjecture which might apply to spectral spaces.

Comment: @Z.M: thanks for pointing that out, I hadn’t clocked that the T_0 assumption was still in force in the final paragraph. In that case, the relevant fixed point theorem should be a trivial consequence of the Lefschetz FPT for simplicial complexes. (Presumably everyone knows this, but I thought I’d mention it explicitly since no one else has yet.)

Comment: @Z. M : but actually yes, if you replace 'contractible' and/or 'absolute extensor' by a condition in terms of the maps of finite spaces, you might get a conjecture about fixed property which applies to spectral spaces. The contractability-like condition on $X$ is that $X\to\{pt\}$ lies in the orthogonal wrt the weak lifting property $f^{lr}$ where $f$ is a map of finite topological spaces which is an acyclic Serre fibration. For some $f$ and $X$ a finite CW complex it does define contractability.

Comment: @HJRW   Don't you need properties like locally connected for good behaviour of singular complexes ?

Comment: @user494312: I said simplicial complexes, which of course are always locally connected. Sorry if I was unclear: I just mean that the FPT for T_0 finite spaces can be proved this way. I have nothing to say about spectral spaces.